# how send a json request to api server by angular4?

Tags: angular

How do I send a request to an API service by using formBuilder in Angular 4 that sends (POST) a JSON file like below to the server ?:

```
{
  "Password": "sample string 1",
  "Identity": {
    "LastName": "sample string 1",
    "FirstName": "sample string 2",
    "NationalCode": "sample string 3",

  }
}
```

I've written the code below but, it doesn't work and the error is : asyncValidator":null

```
registerForm: FormGroup = this.builder.group({
    Password : this.Password ,
    Identity : {
      LastName : this.LastName,
      FirstName : this.FirstName,

    },
  },
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using angular [Http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? It's very unclear. Where do you get that error and when?

Answer (score 0):

You should use httpClient for this purpose.

Please check docs: [Use an HTTP Client to talk to a remote server](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)